# send HTML Code in Textarea to PHP via Form

Tags: html, forms, post, joomla, textarea

i want to have a textarea where I can edit html code directly. After submitting the form the content if the textarea (with html tags) should be saved to a MySQL database. I use PHP to receive the date and save it to the database. My problem is, that the HTML code is not properly sent to PHP. I do not receive the HTML code but just the text. How could I fix this?

my Form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form.php">
   <textarea name="html_code">
      <a href="link">testlink</a>
   </textarea>
   <input type=submit value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The form.php should now be able to show the content of the textarea

```
echo $_POST['html_code'];
```

shows: `testlink`

I want: `<a href="link">testlink</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. I found the problem. It was Joomla. Joomla removed HTML tags when I got strings via getVar. I had to use the mask option JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW to solve the issue.

```
JRequest::getVar('html_code', '', 'post' , 'STRING', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
```

Comment: Hi Dominik, its important to specify in your answer that you are using Joomla etc so people can be aware of the possilbe issues such as this one.

Comment: @Toby Allen yes, you are right. It just didn't occur to me that the problem was Joomla related.

Answer (score 1):

Are you echoing it into an HTML page? Because the code will be parsed into an actual link.

View the source of your output page.

Comment: If I view the source of the HTML page I only see "testlink"

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong encoding type.

Instead of "multipart/form-data", it should be "text/plain".

You don't have to encode the data as Doug says above; but it will be encoded for you when you submit the form, so don't forget to decode before using.

Comment: I don't think encoding is the problem. PHP detects the encoding automatically and decodes what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your form should be:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form.php">
   <textarea name="html_code">
      &lt;a href=&quot;link&quot;&gt;testlink&lt;/a&gt;
   </textarea>
   <input type=submit value="submit"/>
</form>
```

(No, it's not messed up. They're called [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp))

You can use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) in PHP to achieve that.